# Closed Graph of a function and the continuous inverse implies the image is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces, and let $A \subseteq X$ be a subspace.

Suppose $T: A \rightarrow Y$ is a injective linear map with a closed graph.

Let $B=T(A)$.

Show if the inverse map $T_{^{-1}} : B \rightarrow X$ is continuous, then $B$ is closed.

---

Attempt:

Suppose $(y_n) \subset B$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$. Then we want to show $y \in B$.

By the Closed Graph Theorem, we have that $T$ is continuous.

We also know that the restrictions map $A \rightarrow T(A)$ is a bijection.

From here I'm not sure how to continue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The application of the closed graph theorem requires that $A$ is a Banach space, i.e., a closed subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y_n$ is in $B$ convergent to some $y$. It follows that $y_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, since $T_{-1}$ is continuous it is Lipschitz continuous you have that $x_n:=T_{-1}(y_n)$ is also Cauchy, as such it admits a limit $x\in X$.

So $x_n\in A$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ with $T(x_n)=y_n$ also convergent. Since $T$ has closed graph you have that the limits $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.